# Cortex-R5 PMU cycle counter not counting time correctly

Tags: arm

I have the PMU configured correctly for `PMCCNTR` to tick on a Cortex-R5 running FreeRTOS. I will omit the configuration code since it's been repeated on many other StackOverflow questions. I believe the configuration is correctly because I tried running

`__asm__ volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0" : "=r"(pmccntr))`

periodically, and I was able to see that the `pmccntr` variable increases  monotonically and rolls over after (2^32 - 1).

The CPU is running at 800Mhz, so I expected that if I were to read `PMCCNTR` in a 1Hz task I would notice that the value increases by 800Mhz. However, the difference in `PMCCNTR` in between calls to the 1Hz task is more like 72 million. I also tried playing with the 64 clock divider to make sure my observations are sane.

Is my math correct? Or perhaps I am using the wrong number as the CPU frequency? What would be a deterministic way to figure out what frequency the `PMCCNTR` should be counting at?

**Update:** The root cause is WFI as  @Sean Houlihane pointed out

Comment: I'm only able to say that it should be possible to output the internal cpu clock on a IO pin as you haven't given any detailed information about the platform.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane cpu freq can be that high: [search for maximum clock frequency](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-r/cortex-r5)

Comment: cursory search: TI's [RM57L843](http://www.ti.com/product/RM57L843) runs at 330MHz and [Xilinx XCZU7EV-2FBVB900E](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2621630.pdf). R-core: `Maximum RPU clock frequency 600` at speed grade -3. So 800MHz is not that far of and it is literally the developer ARM page. You can't get more first party with your information than that.

Answer (score 1):

The PMCCNTR does run at core clock, so long as the counter is not disabled and the core isn't in debug state. If you calculate 72 MHz/1.125 MHz then there is a good chance your core is running at external crystal frequency, not from the internal PLL.

The other likely explanation is that the core is in WFI state with clocks stopped for most of the time - in which case the result you measure will be influenced by the amount of work done by the OS.

Comment: By "72 MHz/1.125 MHz", do you mean either 72Mhz or 1.125Mhz? Or any number in the range of 1.125-72Mhz? 

What's so special about these frequencies?

Comment: Your made up numbers are annoying. The div64 bit results in a division, that is all. You should know the crystal frequency.